# Rename File Download ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, rename

I have a module in ASP.NET C# that rename an uploaded file to a new one. 
In case, if original file name is: `thisisatext.txt`, when user uploaded into my server it will be renamed to `TXT201302.TXT`.

All activities are recorded to database, with this structure:

```
| id    | oldfilename     | newfilename   |
| 1     | thisisatext.txt | TXT201302.TXT |
```

Now I want to make a download module that rename uploaded file to their original filename, that is: `thisisatext.txt`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the file name in the `Content-Disposition` http header

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + oldfilename);
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

Response.BinaryWrite(fileContents);   //byte array contents of file
Response.End();
```

File will get downloaded, and user will be prompted to save it with the old file name.